# MySQL: "[Err] 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row" when NO rows returned?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, if try to run this query:

```
-- Make sure the variable is typed to a single value...
SET @my_id=300;
SELECT `my_id` INTO @my_id
FROM `my_table` WHERE `field_1`= 123 AND `field_2`IS NULL;
```

...then I get this error:

```
[Err] 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row
```

However, if I run this select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `my_table` WHERE `field_1`= 123 AND `field_2`IS NULL;
```

...then it returns ZERO (ie, no matches).  How is zero more than one?

Comment: Are you sure the error is from this line/statement and not from the previous or the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops... realized what's going on.  The first SELECT INTO statement was being run from inside a procedure, and what it was ACTUALLY calling looked more like this:

```
DECLARE my_id_out INT;
DECLARE field1 INT;
DECLARE field2 INT;

-- do some stuff here to set field1 and field2 variables

SELECT `my_id` INTO my_id_out
FROM `my_table` WHERE `field_1`= field1 AND `field_2`<=> field2;
```

Sooo... the issue was just that it was using the name of the field, instead of the name of my variable, and comparing field1 = field1.

Just renamed the variable, and all is good...